# Querying AWS athena from UTC timezone gives incomplete cost results

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

We have enabled the hourly cost report export to s3 and querying this cost data using the Athena golang API.

*Problem:* We are running our scheduler to get the data from Athena in UTC timezone and getting improper cost values against the query.

Athena and s3 bucket both are configured in us-east-1 region.
We are suspecting that we are not able to get the actual cost values due to timezone mismatch i.e. EST timezone is -05 than UTC. Do we need to run the query in that specific region where Athena and s3 are configured?

Below is the query being used:

```
SELECT
       line_item_product_code as service,
       product_region as region,
       SUM(line_item_blended_cost) as blended_cost                   
FROM 
      <table>
WHERE 
       line_item_usage_start_date BETWEEN from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-03-01T00:00:00+0000') AND from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-03-01T23:59:59+0000')
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: have you tried checking what date you are querying for by running select from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-03-01T00:00:00+0000') to rule out this issue is not happening because of the function?

Comment: I have tried `select from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-03-01T00:00:00+0000') as date from <table>` and got time back as UTC date _2020-03-01 00:00:00.000 UTC_

Comment: Did you figure this one out? :)

Comment: @Roelant unfortunately no more working on this :)